# Using my database class with other classes in my project

Tags: php, database, oop, class, object

I have a custom database class that I wrote myself, and I also have a user class and a site class.

The MySQL class has methods like this:

```
connect
query
clean
fetch
```

The user class:

```
register
login
logout
resetPass
```

The site class:

```
updateTopics
addTopic
addPost
addReply
```

etc.

These classes need to interface with a database, which is what I wrote the MySQL class for. But, I have no idea how to properly use the MySQL class with these classes. Do I define the class as global and just reference it in the other classes? Do I do something like:

```
$db = new MySQL();
$user = new User($db);
```

and then reference it like that?

Any help is appreciated, thank you. :)

Comment: Where do you keep the database handle? In the MySQL class don't you?

Comment: When you make the first connection to the database you need to save the handle that refers to it. Why I am asking about where the handle is stored is because if you do so in the MySQL class, you will be making a new connection for every instantiation. If you really want a stellar system, perhaps make a connection pool (that acts as a singleton) and then use some IOC container like VolkerK suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Daniel Vandersluis's answer:
Instantiating the object within your class creates a strong dependency between those classes. You might instead be interested in dependency injection and inversion of control (+ ioc containers).

see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection
http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

---

btw: Do you *really* need your own MySQL class implementation? There are already so many database access and abstraction layers available. E.g. http://docs.php.net/pdo.

Answer (score 1):

you might be interested in stantiating the MySql class just one time. it prevents the connection to be opened and closed many times during execution. i like to use the Factory concept. it's a class that handle the instantiation of objects and you can write it to allow only one instance, following the Singleton concept.

someting like this:

```
class Factory {

    private static $objects = array();

    static function get_database() {

        if( ! isset(self::$objects['database']))
            self::$objects['database'] = new MySql();

        return self::$objects['database'];
    }
}
```

you would use like that:

```
$db = Factory::get_database();
```

note that it always return the same instance of MySql instead of creating new ones.

well, but it's just a very simple implementation of a Factory, just for understanding. it could be a lot better =]

Comment: Ah yeah, that kinda makes more sense. So the Factory class basically holds all the other objects I'm using at one time? Does this mean if I was to use this method I would have to do something like `Factory::whatever();` every time I use any class?

Comment: just the ones that you want to prevent from being instantiated many times. well, it's not the only solution. like i said, it's just the one that i like. but it doesn't do only that. this factory could help you to concentrate your class dependences and facilitate the configuration of them. what i don't reccomend is that you do `new MySql` every time you use the database.

Answer (score -1):

You could instantiate your `MySQL` class within your other classes, like so:

```
class User
{
  private $db;

  function __construct(...)
  {
    $this->db = new MySQL();
  }

  function accesses_database(...)
  {
    $this->db->query(...);
  }
}
```

And then reference `$this->db` inside your class when you want to access the database.

Also, if you want there to only be one instantiation of `MySQL`, you can make it a [singleton](https://www.php.net/singleton).

Comment: I voted this down because I think it is actually bad solution. Eg see http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/